Finding number of ways of flipping a coin until getting HTH while specifically NOT getting HHH (ARML 2024)
The original question is as follows, from ARML 2024:
Marcelo and Marta play a game in which a fair coin is flipped repeatedly. The coin either lands heads (H) or tails (T). They play until three consecutive flips appear in the order HTH or HHH. If HTH appears first, then Marcelo wins; otherwise, Marta wins. Compute the number of distinct sequences of coin flips that result in Marcelo winning on the tenth flip.
The official solution is as follows:

Let $W_n$ be the number of flip sequences in which Marcelo wins on the
$n$th flip. Observe that:

$W_1 = W_2 = 0$ because the game requires at least 3 flips to win,
$W_3 = 1$ if the squence is HTH,
$W_4 = 2$ from HHTH or THTH.

Now suppose $n ≥ 5$ and consider a “Marcelo-winning” sequence of $n$
flips. Depending on whether this winning sequence begins with $0, 1,$
or $2$ heads, it must start with T, HTT, or HHTT, respectively, and
then be followed by a winning sequence of length $4, 2,$ or $1,$
respectively. This yields the recursion
$$ W_n = W_{n-1} + W_{n-3} + W_{n-4} $$ The next few terms are
therefore $W_5 = 2, W_6 = 3, W_7 = 6, W_8 = 10, W_9 = 15$ and ${W_{10}
 }= 24.$

I did not understand how we said that the sequences of 0, 1, 2 heads would be followed by a winning sequence of 4, 2, or 1. I especially did not understand how we found the recursion.
Any help is appreciated.

I am, also, unsure what exact tags to put this question under.

Think about what state the game is in at any moment, labeling the states by how much of a potential winner (for either side) you have running.  Thus the states can be thought of as $START, H, HH, HT, WIN, LOSS$.  Where WIN/LOSS are from Marcelo's point of view.  Given that the game can't end in the first four tosses, a good sequence begins with one of $T,HTT, HHTT$ after which it returns to START. The desired recursion follows from that remark.
I agree that the official write up is a bit odd.  Presumably they meant to say something like "and then be followed by a winning sequence of length $n-1, n-3, n-4$", but the overall logic is clear enough.

I believe it was a typo. The sentence "sequence begins with 0, 1, or 2 heads (would be) followed by a winning sequence of length 4, 2, or 1 ..." refers specifically to the case $n=5$.
Following the observation for the case $n=5$, a winning sequence of $n$ flips that begins with 0, 1, or 2 heads would be followed by a winning sequence of length $n-1$, $n-3$, or $n-4$, respectively, which then yields the recursive equation provided.
